# Lua - 'system' is unavailable: not available in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, lua

I have opened an IOS Objetive C project that uses Lua in xCode 9 (which was working in xCode 8) and I get the following error:

```
'system' is unavailable: not available in iOS
```

**ioslib.c**
[image]

I know that 'system' is unavailable in iOS11 but how can I fix this issue with Lua?  This is a library that I have included and did not write myself.

Comment: See these threads: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2017-09/msg00235.html and http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2017-09/msg00217.html.

Comment: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2017-09/msg00242.html

Answer (score 1):

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2017-09/msg00242.html

disabled in luaconf.h by default:

```
#if defined(__APPLE__)
     #include "TargetConditionals.h"
     #if TARGET_OS_IOS || TARGET_OS_WATCH || TARGET_OS_TV
         #define system(s) ((s)==NULL ? 0 : -1)
     #endif // end iOS
#elif defined(__ANDROID__)
     #define system(s) ((s)==NULL ? 0 : -1)
#endif
```